# How to compute the 90% distribution value from a set of number in java or linux command line?

Tags: java, distribution

I ran my integration test and got a list of execution time back. I need to find the 90% distribution value from that set of result not the average. Because it represents what the user will encounter 90% of the time. Is there a linux command line that does that? If not is there a java library that does that?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Without any knowledge of what the output looks like, it's all guesswork. The problem statement sounds like it could be solved in about two lines of `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a file with each measurement on a separate line, with the actual measurement in the first column, count the lines, call that number L; sort reversed, print the first field from the L/10th line. How you round a non-integer L/10 is up to you; you could also interpolate a value between n(floor(L/10)) and n(ceil(L/10)).

```
#!/bin/sh
L=$(wc -l <data.txt)
sort -r -n data.txt |
awk "NR >= $L/10"'{print $1; exit}'
```

This assumes fields are whitespace-separated.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a 90th [percentile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile). Simply sort the execution times from shortest to longest and pick the one lying 10% from the end. The quoted article explains other methods.

You can easily implement this using Java or Unix commands: `sort`, `wc`, `head` and `tail` or `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

If you store your times in a List or an array you can do this.

> If not is there a java library that does that?

Its just a couple of lines of Java code.  I would just add it to your Java program so you have less output to deal with.

```
List<Long> times = new ArrayList<>();
// add times
Collections.sort(times);
System.out.printf("The typical, 90%% and 99%%tile times were %,d / %,d / %,d %n",
   times.get(times.size()/2), times.get(times.size()*9/10), times.get(times.size()*99/100));
```

or

```
long[] times = new long[SAMPLES];
// add times and
Arrays.sort(times);
System.out.printf("The typical, 90%% and 99%%tile times were %,d / %,d / %,d %n",
   times[SAMPLES/2], times[SAMPLES*9/10], times[SAMPLES*99/100]);
```

> Because it represents what the user will encounter 90% of the time.

Actually the 90th percentile is the time its will less than 90% of the time. The user will only experience this delay (or more) 10% of the time.